# DomainCheck via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm making an online calculator, and one thing I got stuck - how to check is domain (submitted by user) available or not and show user the result without page reload.
If someone know how to do it, please tell me how :)

Comment: available to purchase? or just a valid domain?

Comment: can u please try to explain some more details? I cannot get the link between checking if a domain is available and an online calculator :)

Comment: Domain available for purchase (using Whois request, I guess)

Comment: This calculator involves domain registration and hosting services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get it for free.  There's [Whois API](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/) as an example of a for-money service. Even that one, however, doesn't have a JSONP API.

Because such services are not free, you'd generally have to provide them with some sort of API key for authentication and billing.  Therefore, you certainly wouldn't want that embedded in your client-side code anyway.